# Dealing with abusive use of editing on one's own questions

Tags: discussion, editing

I've come across multiple questions from the same user, the last one being [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105646/ajax-add-to-cart-working-but-add-to-cart-not-working-for-configurable-products).
As you can see, it has an extended amount of edits, consisting mainly of adding and removing "..." from a sentence.
This was done as to appear on the top of the question feed (I don't see any other reason), although the question has a bounty on it.

My question is: what can we do to prevent such behaviours? Am I supposed to flag all his questions (because that's clearly what he does every time: [17 posts edited / 744 revisions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12982/baby-in-magento?tab=activity&sort=revisions))?

**UPDATE**:
Looks like he's been using a different strategy to get people's attention, for example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/107132/revisions) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/104326/revisions), he's just edited the whole question to ask a new one.
I do think that obnoxious behaviour should be delt with once and for all. His questions don't bring anything interesting for the community, he just want his website(s) done by people from Magento SE no matter what. He should hire someone in that case and not spam Magento SE for his work to be done in his place.

**UPDATE 2**:
I don't mean to sound like a crybaby (see what I did there? ;)) but it looks like he didn't get it and still tries to get attention no matter what. I was on StackOverflow looking up at the Magento questions when I stumbled upon [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549558/display-least-selling-seller-name-on-top-of-the-view-page) which looks exactly like [this one on Magento SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109712/display-least-selling-seller-name-on-top-of-the-view-page). Please take action, this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that user behavior several times. He tends to be a help vampire, not a big deal. I reckon only a moderator will be able to help you here, the only post I've found on Meta SE is this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature

Comment: The first 2 answers seem to indicate that this is indeed an abusive behaviour.

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if you're supposed to flag all of them or it wouldn't be better if a moderator takes it to another level.

Comment: Looks like now he tries to protect questions with a bounty. I just stumbled over one of that user and that he should hire someone was my very first impression. Questions are of very little quality, I see no efforts and it's just asking for code in a very bad style. Mageno SE is too small in scope to have anything from that ... .

Answer (score 10):

Consider it handled. I warned user to stop, and I/we will suspend if it continues. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Hope he'll come to reason before you have to act. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the same user changed tactics https://twitter.com/foomanNZ/status/713127176799789057

Comment: Well, maybe he needs answers, who knows. Or someone do work for him.

Comment: What if it's a one time incident? I just came across this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/107083/revisions

Comment: I'm inclined to see if it is persistent behavior over a majority of a given user's questions.